# Intuition behind $E(X-t \; |\; X>t) = E(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda }$ in exponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ be a an exponentially distributed random variable with rate $\lambda $ and let $t$ be a constant.

It was shown to me that 
$$E(X-t \; |\; X>t) = E(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda }$$

However, the steps were not shown how to get from the first to the second part. I understand the memoryless property of the exponential distribution but I do not quite see how they are utilizing this to go from the first to the second part.

I am hoping someone can clarify the intuition behind this.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48496/conditional-expectation-of-exponential-random-variable

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I see now. It is the shift and then the reverse shift that cancel. Thank you for the link

Comment: $$ E(X-t \; |\; X>t) = E(X \; |\; X>t) - E(t \; |\; X>t) =E(X) + t -t = E(X) =\frac{1}{\lambda } $$ where we use linearity of expectation and then the memoryless property of the Exponential.

Comment: @HJ_beginner your comment is very helpful. It is exactly what my thought was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (originally) accepted answer is wrong -it has two errors than cancel out- , it could be fixed but it would still be too complex. The comment of HJ_beginner fits the bill.

First: 
$$E(X-t \; |\; X>t) = E(X \; |\; X>t) - E(t \; |\; X>t) $$

This, because of linearity of (conditional or not) expectation: $E(A+B \mid C)= E(A \mid  C) + E(B\mid C)$

Then, $E(t \; |\; X>t)=t$ (expectation of a constant).

And the memoryless property implies that the statistics of $X$ conditioned on $X>t$ are equivalent to the original but shifted a "time" $t$. Hence $E(X \; |\; X>t) = E(X) + t = 1/\lambda +t$.

Hence $E(X-t \; |\; X>t) = E(X)=1/\lambda$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Set $Y=X\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}$. Then
$$\mathbb E[X\mid X>a]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P\{X>a\}}\mathbb E[X\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P\{X>a\}}\mathbb E[Y]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P\{X>a\}}\int_{\mathbb R}yf_Y(y)dy.$$

Now, $$\mathbb P\{Y>y\}=\mathbb P\{X\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}>y\}=\mathbb P\{X>y\mid X>a\}\mathbb P\{X>a\}=\mathbb P\{X>(y-a)+a\mid X>a\}\mathbb P\{X>a\}=\mathbb P\{X>y-a\}\mathbb P\{X>a\},$$
where the last equality comes from the memoryless property. Therefore, $$f_Y(y)=\mathbb P\{X>a\}f_{X}(y-a).$$

Now, it's just calculation.

Comment: You have to calculate $\Bbb E[X-a\ \vert\ X>a].$ Right? Though that can be calculated using linearity of conditional expectation.

Comment: The fact that $\mathbb E[X\mid X>a]=\mathbb E[X]+a$ was not clear for me as far as I did the calculations. But indeed, if it's clear for you, just do it :-) @Dbchatto67

Comment: It is due to the memoryless property of the exponential distribution @user657324 which is a very standard result. Anyway your answer is good enough to get an upvote at least which no one has given yet. So I upvoted it.

Comment: are you sure?  I think $$\mathbb E[X\mid X>a]=\frac{\mathbb E[X\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}]}{P(X>a)}$$  since $$E(X|A)=\frac{E(X1_A)}{P(A)}$$

Comment: but you write $$\mathbb E[X\mid X>a]=\mathbb E[X\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}]$$

Comment: @masoud: Thank you. You are absolutely right.

Comment: This answer is wrong, it has two errors that cancel themselves.  The first equality is wrong, actually $E[X\mid X>a]=\mathbb E[X\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}]$. And $\mathbb P\{X\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}>y\}=\mathbb P\{X>y\mid X>a\}$ is also wrong https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170834/why-mathbb-px-boldsymbol-1-xa-y-mathbb-pxy-mid-xa/3171376#3171376

Comment: @leonbloy: You completely right, thank you. I edited my answer.