# Why $\mathbb P(X\boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}>y)=\mathbb P(X>y\mid X>a)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170730/intuition-behind-ex-t-xt-ex-frac1-lambda-in-exponential-di/3170811#3170811) in the answer of **user657324** that $$\mathbb P(X\boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}>y)=\mathbb P(X>y\mid X>a),\tag{*}$$
but I don't really understand why it's true. I try to ask directely to user657324, but it looks that I can't leave any comment. So why $(*)$ is true ? And in general, do we have that $$\mathbb P(XY>z)=\mathbb P(X>z\mid Y)=\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{X>z\}}\mid Y]\ \ ?$$
And if yes, why ?

Comment: Could it be (*) assumes $y>0$ and then RHS should be $\mathbb{P}[X>y,X>a]$?

Comment: @gt6989b: Sorry, I don't get the question. You mean that $\mathbb P(X\boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}>y)=\mathbb P(X>y,X>a)$ ?

Comment: You can leave a comment there. There is no reason to discuss the answer here. Especially because the thread is active.

Comment: @callculus: I tried, but it's written that I need 50 reputations to comment (I don't understand what it is... I need to be a member for 50 days ?) Thank you for your answer.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with the time of membership. You get reputations for asking questions and answering questions etc. You should have become 5 points for reputation for an upvote of your question in the last 16 minutes. In your situation it is OK to post your question. I´ll upvote your question in a few seconds. See what happens.

Comment: @callculus: I see, thank you to authorize me to ask a question :) (I wasn't sure if I were allowed or not). Good to know anyway. Best wishes,

Comment: I´m not in the position to authorize something :) Subjects which are posted multiple times are not welcomed here. But in your case I think it is OK.

Comment: The linked (and accepted) answer is just wrong. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks wrong to me. If $y>0$, the event $X\boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}>y$ is equivalent to $X>a \cap X>y$, or equivalently  $X>\max(a,y)$.

More in detail, calling $Z = 1_{\{X>a\}}$ :

$$\begin{align}
P(X Z >y) &= P(X Z >y , Z=0) + P(X Z >y, Z=1) \\
&= P(X Z >y \mid Z=0) P(Z=0) +  P(X Z >y \mid Z=1) P(Z=1)  \\
&= 0 P(Z=0) +P(X >y \mid Z=1) P(Z=1) \\
&= P(X > y \mid X>a) P(X>a)\\
&= P(X > y , X>a) \\
&= P(X > \max(y,a)) 
\end{align}
$$

BTW: the [linked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3170811/312) gets the correct result in spite of this error, because it has another error (the first equality) and they cancel out. Actually $E[X\mid X>a]=\mathbb E[X\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{\{X>a\}}]$.

Answer (score 0):

it seem not correct.

$$\mathbb P(XY>z)=\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb E(1_A)=\mathbb E(\mathbb E(1_A|Y))=\mathbb E(\mathbb P(A|Y))=\mathbb E(\mathbb P(XY>z|Y))$$

and

$$\mathbb E(\mathbb P(XY>z|Y=y))=\mathbb E(\mathbb P(Xy>z|Y=y))$$

and it is depend on $y<0$ or $y\geq 0$.

if $Y=1_{X>a}$ so $Y\sim Ber(p=P(X>a))$

$$\mathbb P(XY>z)=\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb E(1_A)=\mathbb E(\mathbb E(1_A|Y))=
\mathbb E(g(Y))$$

$$=P(Y=1) * g(1) +P(Y=0) * g(0)$$

$$=P(Y=1) * E(1_A|Y=1)+P(Y=0)*E(1_A|Y=0)$$

$$=P(Y=1) * P(A|Y=1)+P(Y=0)*P(A|Y=0)$$

$$=P(1_{X>a}=1) * P(X1_{X>a}>z|1_{X>a}=1)+P(1_{X>a}=0)*P(X1_{X>a}>z|1_{X>a}=0)$$

$$=P(1_{X>a}=1) * P(X>z|1_{X>a}=1)+P(1_{X>a}=0)*P(0>z|1_{X>a}=0)$$

note $P(0>z|1_{X>a}=0)$ is alwayes is 1 or zero

$$=P(X>a) * P(X>z|X>a)+P(X\leq a)*P(0>z|X\leq a)$$

for example if $z\geq 0$

$$=P(X>a) * P(X>z|X>a)+0=P(X>z , X>a)=P(X>max(a,z))$$

but if $z<0$

$$=P(X>a) * P(X>z|X>a)+P(X\leq a)=P(X>max(a,z))+P(X\leq a)$$